# How to Move All USING Statements to top of Project Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I used REFLECTOR to disassemble an older DLL of mine.  The problem is it added the USING statements INSIDE the namespace.  I need them to all sit in the outside.  Take a look below.  How can I accomplish this?  From inside Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: This is a valid practice. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You could introduce potential scoping issues (like namespace conflicts) if the usings were placed within the namespace by intention.

Comment: I have hundreds of code files in this project, moving them myself really isn't a valid option.  I have scope issues now as Quintin mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice is to only use one root namespace in a file, so I don't see why it would matter if they're inside or out... but anyway, the solution is...

***<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>***
***<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>***

Answer (score 1):

Search Replace in VS with Regular Expression. untested

```
replace "^(namespace .+)(using.+)public" with "$2$1"
```